# pdsh gives error "rcmd: socket: Permission denied"

Tags: ssh

When I run the command:

`pdsh -w host1,host2 tail -f /var/log/apache.log`

I get the following error:

```
pdsh@myhost: host2: rcmd: socket: Permission denied
pdsh@myhost: host1: rcmd: socket: Permission denied
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Found the answer. rcmd_default needs an entry:

`echo "ssh" > /etc/pdsh/rcmd_default`

Comment: Don't know why this was downvoted. It solves the issue for me. If it didn't work for the downvoter then they should have made a comment.

Comment: Agreed. This also worked for me.

Comment: Worked for me too. (Well, I needed to create and hand-edit `rcmd_default` because I got permission denied even with `sudo echo ...`, but same diff.) Thanks.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien Bit off topic, but the reason ```sudo echo ...``` doesn't work is because you are running the echo command as root, but then trying to redirect the output as regular user. This would work:

```echo "ssh" | sudo tee /etc/pdsh/rcmd_default```

Comment: Super. Thanks for leaving that follow up. FTR, I ended up going with `echo 'echo "ssh" > /etc/pdsh/rcmd_default' | sudo -s`, using the construct given in a top-voted comment [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10134932/980833).

Comment: This solution works but requires root access. A solution not requiring root access is to use the `-R` option to specify `ssh` as the module that you would like to use. Your specific command would be the following: `pdsh -R ssh -w host1,host2 tail -f /var/log/apache.log`

Comment: Yes, this worked for me too and I have upvoted.  Now, it would be interesting to know where in the documentation this is explained because I could not find it anywhere in the manpage

Answer (score 4):

You can use `PDSH_RCMD_TYPE=ssh` like:

`PDSH_RCMD_TYPE=ssh pdsh -w host1,host2 tail -f /var/log/apache.log`

Comment: this solution works (unlike the original) since I cannot modify /etc/. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

On Fedora 23 to get this working I had to:

Install pdsh-rcmd-ssh which makes SSH an available rcmd module

```
dnf install pdsh-rcmd-ssh
```

Export the following variable

```
export PDSH_RCMD_TYPE=ssh
```